# Defining "has_many through: assocation" with scoped conditionals in the through model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, associations

I have a schema that looks something like this:

```rb
create_table "customers" do |t|
  t.integer "customer_number"
end

create_table "past_payments" do |t|
  t.integer  "customer_number"

  t.datetime "transaction_date"
  t.integer  "arbitrary_sequence_number"
end

create_table "payment_details" do |t|
  t.datetime "transaction_date"
  t.integer  "arbitrary_sequence_number"
end
```

TL;DR from the schema - A Customer is associated with a past_payment through a primary/foreign key. And a PastPayment is associated with a single PaymentDetail when their transaction_date AND arbitrary_sequence_number are equal. Payments and Details have no formal primary/foreign key relationship.

That gives me the following ActiveRecord models:

```rb
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :past_payments, foreign_key: :customer_number, primary_key: :customer_number

  has_many :payment_details, through: :past_payments # unfortunately, broken 
end

class PastPayment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :payment_detail, ->(past_payment) {
    where(arbitrary_sequence_number: past_payment.arbitrary_sequence_number)
  }, foreign_key: :transaction_date, primary_key: :transaction_date
end
```

Since a `Customer has_many :past_payments` and a `PastPayment has_one :payment_detail`, I would think there's an association that can be defined such that a `Customer has_many :payment_details, through: :past_payments`, but I can't get that to work because of the scope defined on the `has_one :payment_detail` association.

Specifically, calling `Customer.payment_details` raises the `NoMethodError: undefined method 'arbitrary_sequence_number' for #<Customer:0x2i8asdf3>`. So it would seem the Customer is getting passed to my scope as opposed to the PastPayment.

Is it possible to define the `has_many :payment_details` association on the Customer? Am I doing something wrong?

To be clear, I'd like to be able to say `Customer.where(some_conditions).includes(:payment_details)` and execute just the two queries so if there's a way to accomplish that without associations, I'm open to it.

**Note:** I can't change this database. It's a database some other application writes to, and I need to read from it.

Unrelated to my question, here's the workaround I'm currently working with. If there is no way to properly use associations, I'd be happy to have this solution critiqued:

```rb
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_writer :payment_details

  def payment_details
    @payment_details ||= Array(self).with_payment_details.payment_details
  end

  module InjectingPaymentData
    def with_payment_details
      results = self.to_a
      return self unless results.first.is_a?(Customer)

      user_ids = results.collect(&:id)

      # i've omitted the details of the query, but the idea is at the end of it
      # we have a hash with the customer_number as a key pointing to an array
      # of PaymentDetail objects
      payment_details = PaymentDetails.joins().where().group_by(&:customer_number)

      results.each do |customer|
        customer.payment_details = Array(payment_details[customer.customer_number])
      end
    end
  end
end

ActiveRecord::Relation.send(:include, Customer::InjectingPaymentData)
Array.send(:include, Customer::InjectingPaymentData)
```

And with that I can do things like the following with minimal querying:

```or-tag-here
@customers = Customer.where(id: 0..1000).with_payment_details
@customers.each { |c| do_something_with_those_payment_details }
```

Problems with that approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leverage this gem to better handle "composite primary keys" in ActiveRecord: https://github.com/composite-primary-keys/composite_primary_keys

```rb
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :past_payments, foreign_key: :customer_number, primary_key: :customer_number

  has_many :payment_details, through: :past_payments # this works now
end

class PastPayment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :payment_detail, foreign_key: [:transaction_date, :arbitrary_sequence_number],
                           primary_key: [:transaction_date, :arbitrary_sequence_number]
end
```